# merge intervals without using loops and classic python code

Tags: python, overloading, data-analysis

my problem is to merge intervals where I have the overlapping 
example:

```
input: 
[(4,8),(6,10),(11,12),(15,20),(20,25)] 
output: 
[(4, 10),(11,12), (15, 25)]
input: 
([(4,8),(6,10),(11,12),(15,20)])
output: 
[(4, 10),(11,12), (15, 20)]
```

I did it with classic python code(using loops, if conditions)
BUT I want to do it with python libraries (pandas, numpy..) in few lines
is there any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show how you did it in plain Python?

Comment: Since `(6,10)` doesn't overlap with `(11,12)`, why `(4, 12)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge overlapping numeric ranges into continuous ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317211/merge-overlapping-numeric-ranges-into-continuous-ranges)

Comment: yes thank you @Chris for the correction if we change (6,10) by (6,11) the output will be fine

Comment: I was wondering why this question got 3 downvotes (showing 2 because of my upvote ), without any explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your input tuples are sorted like in the examples, something like this does the job:

```
p = [(4, 8), (6, 10), (11, 12), (15, 20), (20, 25)] 

ind = np.where(np.diff(np.array(p).flatten()) <= 0)[0]
np.delete(p, [ind, ind+1]).reshape(-1, 2)
```

output:

```
array([[ 4, 10],
       [11, 12],
       [15, 25]])
```

Then you can convert it to `[(4, 10), (11, 12), (15, 25)]` using e.g. `list(map(tuple, ...))`.

---

**Edit**: the above works only if each tuple `(x_i, y_i)` is such that  `x_i <= x_{i+1}` and `y_i <= y_{i+1}` for all i's, as in the original examples.

To make it work with the only condition `x_i <= y_i` for all `i`, you have to preprocess the list:

```
# Example from comments (modified by subtracting the min value and removing duplicates)
p = [(0, 90), (72, 81), (87, 108), (459, 606)]

p = list(zip(sorted([tup[0] for tup in p]), sorted([tup[1] for tup in p])))

ind = np.where(np.diff(np.array(p).flatten()) <= 0)[0]
ind = ind[ind % 2 == 1]  # this is needed for cases when x_i = y_i
np.delete(p, [ind, ind+1]).reshape(-1, 2)
```

Output:

```
array([[  0, 108],
       [459, 606]])
```

Comment: for this example: [(9466848, 9466938), (9466920, 9466929), (9466935, 9466956), (9467307, 9467454), (9467307, 9467454), (9467307, 9467454), (9467307, 9467454), (9467307, 9467454), (9467307, 9467454)]

, it doesn't give the correct result which is : [array([9466848, 9466929]),
 array([9466935, 9466956]),
 array([9467307, 9467454])] in order of [array([9466848, 9466956]),
 array([9467307, 9467454])]

Comment: Thank you @AndyK now it works fine :D, by the way, do you recommend any useful resource to learn numpy / pandas :)

Comment: @asmatrk I mostly learned (and keep learning) numpy from documentation and by googling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is necessarily the best option, since it takes `O(max_interval_value * num_intervals)` time and memory, but this is a straightforward implementation with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

def simplify_intervals(intervals):
    # Make intervals into an array
    intervals = np.asarray(intervals)
    # Make array for zero to the greatest interval end (plus bounds values
    r = np.arange(intervals[:, 1].max() + 3)[:, np.newaxis]
    # Check what elements of the array are within each interval
    m = (r >= intervals[:, 0] + 1) & (r <= intervals[:, 1] + 1)
    # Collapse belonging test for each value
    ind = m.any(1).astype(np.int8)
    # Find where the belonging test changes
    d = np.diff(ind)
    # Find interval bounds
    start = np.where(d > 0)[0]
    end = np.where(d < 0)[0] - 1
    # Make final intervals array
    return np.stack((start, end), axis=1)

print(simplify_intervals([(4, 8), (6, 10), (11, 12), (15, 20), (20, 25)]))
# [[ 4 12]
#  [15 25]]
print(simplify_intervals(([(4,8),(6,10),(11,12),(15,20)])))
# [[ 4 12]
#  [15 20]]
```

Note: This assumes positive interval values. It could be adapted to support negative ranges, and actually optimized a bit to only consider values from the smallest one to the largest one.

EDIT:

If you want to use this method for large number of intervals or bounds, you may benefit from using Numba instead:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def simplify_intervals_nb(intervals):
    n = 0
    for _, end in intervals:
        n = max(n, end)
    r = np.arange(n + 3)
    m = np.zeros(n + 3, dtype=np.bool_)
    for start, end in intervals:
        m |= (r >= start + 1) & (r <= end + 1)
    ind = m.astype(np.int8)
    # Find where the belonging test changes
    d = np.diff(ind)
    # Find interval bounds
    start = np.where(d > 0)[0]
    end = np.where(d < 0)[0] - 1
    # Make final intervals array
    return np.stack((start, end), axis=1)
```

Quick test in IPython:

```
import random

random.seed(100)
start = [random.randint(0, 10000) for _ in range(300)]
end = start = [s + random.randint(0, 3000) for s in start]
intervals = list(zip(start, end))
print(np.all(simplify_intervals(intervals) == simplify_intervals_nb(intervals)))
# True
%timeit simplify_intervals(intervals)
# 15.2 ms ± 179 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit simplify_intervals_nb(intervals)
# 9.54 ms ± 146 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer @jdehesa but I have just made an error in my question which is: (6,10) doesn't overlap with (11,12), so the output1 should be:
[(4, 10),(11,12), (15, 25)] and the output2: [(4, 10),(11,12), (15, 20)] what should I change in this code to have the correct result. thank you  in advance

Comment: @asmatrk So you mean the intervals are supposed to be real-valued? (that is, there are values between `(6, 10)` and `(11, 12)` that do not belong to any interval) The method above is designed for integer intervals, so `(4, 10), (11, 12)` would be equivalent to `(4, 12)`.